# Please correct my javascript code

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-enterprise, javascript, jquery, html

Please i need help with my script,I want my page to generate thumbnails directly being read from a share point list, below is the already existing code :

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
       jQuery(document).ready(function($){

          var doc_lib = "HrOne Document Library";
          var doc_name = "Name";
          var doc_office = "Office";
          var doc_type = "Type";
          var doc_title = "Title"; // Name of the list that contains slides
          var department = "Created By"; //Name of the Rich text field that has slide content


          doc_thumb(doc_lib,doc_name,doc_type,doc_title,department);
      });
     function doc_thumb(doc_lib,doc_name,doc_type,doc_title,department) {
         //query to retrieve all items
         var query = "<Query><Where><Neq><FieldRef Name='ID' /><Value Type='Number'></Value></Neq></Where></Query>";
         //return fields for slide content and background picture
         var camlViewFields = "<ViewFields><FieldRef Name='"+doc_name+"' /><FieldRef Name='"+doc_type+"' /><FieldRef 

Name='"+doc_title+"' /><FieldRef Name='"+department+"' /></ViewFields>";
         $().SPServices({
              operation: "GetListItems",
              async: true,
              listName: doc_lib,
              CAMLViewFields: camlViewFields,
              CAMLQuery: query,
              completefunc:function(xData, Status) {
                   $(xData.responseXML).SPFilterNode("z:row").each(function() {
                   var name = ($(this).attr("ows_"+doc_name));
                    var type = ($(this).attr("ows_"+doc_type));
                   var title =($(this).attr("ows_"+doc_title));
                   var url = $(this).attr("ows_EncodedAbsUrl") + "";
                   var li_thumb = " <li> <article class="portfolio-item pf-documents">
                            <div class="portfolio-image">
                                <a href="portfolio-single.html">
                                    <img src="/sites/cbn/SiteAssets/images/portfolio/4/5.jpg" alt="Console Activity"/>
                                </a>
                                &nbsp;&nbsp;<div class="portfolio-overlay">
                                    <a href="/sites/cbn/SiteAssets/images/portfolio/full/5.jpg" class="left-icon" data-

lightbox="image"><i class="icon-line-plus"></i></a>
                                    <a href="portfolio-single.html" class="right-icon"><i class="icon-line-ellipsis"></i></a>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                             <div class="portfolio-desc">
                                <h3><a href="portfolio-single.html">"+name+"</a></h3>
                                <span><a href="#">Documents</a>  <a href="#">"+creator+"</a></span>
                            </div>
                        </article></li> ";

 var creator=$(this).attr("ows_"+department)==undefined?"":$(this).attr("ows_"+department).split(",")[0];

                   //create slide (li) and append it to other slides
                   $("#generate").append("li_thumb");
              }); // end completefunc
              //start the slider

            }
         }); // end SPServices call

     }
 </script>
```

I just want other eyes to point out what im doing wrong so i can correct it.

Here is the html code it appends to :

```
<div  class="col_two_third portfolio-single-image nobottommargin col_last">
                    <ul id="generate">

                    </ul>

</div>
```

I want the script to append the article in the html code from a SharePoint document library, but it is not working at all. so i just feel like i'm doing something wrong.

Comment: Have you checked the console (F12) for errors after running this? That is always a good place to start when JS code isn't working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest to use a simple IDE to develop your code. This IDE will help you by finding simple errors. A free example for a IDE is [Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/) but there are loads of IDE's for you to choose.

Here's the output if I paste your code: 
[image]

After knowing the simple errors fixing is not the problem - at least the ones caused by bad syntax.